# UIButton is taking 3 taps before working? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, uibutton, swift2

[image: button]I have a button as seen in the image and when the user presses it first it should change the image and the user is now following this profile. However when the user presses the button first it does nothing and on the second tap it works. How can I make this work on the first tap?

**Edit cleaned up code** This code takes two taps for the button to work. With a double tap it follows or unfollows the user and updates the image. But like i said it takes two taps.

```
 @IBAction func favButton(sender: UIButton) {

    buttonPressed = !buttonPressed


            if buttonPressed == true {

                let followedObjectId = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String

                if isFollowing[followedObjectId!] == true {


                }

            } else  {

                let followedObjectId = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String

                if isFollowing[followedObjectId!] == false {

                    isFollowing[followedObjectId!] = true
                    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "fave_on@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)


                    print("follow")

                    let following = PFObject(className: "Followers")
                    following["following"] = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String
                    following["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
                    favLabel.text = "Favourite Jammer"

                    following.saveInBackground()

                } else {

                    if buttonPressed != true {

                        isFollowing[followedObjectId!] = false
                        print("notFollow")
                        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "fave_off@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                        favLabel.text = "Add to favourites?"

                    }

                }
            }
```

**This code fixed it visually, but it no longer works behind the scenes.** The button changes image and prints follow and unfollow to the logs but it doesn't unfollow a user and also adds the followed user to my data twice.

```
        buttonPressed = !buttonPressed

    if buttonPressed == true {

        let followedObjectId = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String

        isFollowing[followedObjectId!] = true

        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "fave_on@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        print("follow")

        let following = PFObject(className: "Followers")
        following["following"] = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String
        following["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
        favLabel.text = "Favourite Jammer"

        following.saveInBackground()

    } else {

        if buttonPressed != true {
            let followedObjectId = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String

            isFollowing[followedObjectId!] = false
            print("notFollow")
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "fave_off@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            favLabel.text = "Add to favourites?"

        } // !=true
    } // else

} // uibutton
```

Comment: The code is a bit messy... The initial query should be in the `ViewDidLoad` so that the values are there before the button is pressed. Then the rest of the logic when the button is pressed also needs to be in a separate function and broken down into pieces. Too much is happening in that button.

Comment: when you linked the button to your class (ctrl + drag from interface builder to the view Controller) did you do it from touch up inside of the button (ctrl + click on the  button and tell me if the connection is in touch up inside

Comment: Kholl ya it is in touch up inside. @likeslvi ok ill try clean her up a bit and see if that improves it.

Comment: I'm writing an answer to help improve your code. But the image changing should be happening within the button while everything else (queries, changing the data, etc, needs to be happening within functions and within the viewDidLoad before hand. Once its like this, you can easily change the image.

Comment: ok thanks very much @lukeslvi

Comment: Why are you making 2 queries to update the followers/following?

Comment: Ya I just noticed that I have deleted the code above `buttonPressed = !buttonPressed` no need for it sorry im a complete newb...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is a very messy and I wouldn't recommend going about it like this... Too many queries are happening and too much in general is going on in that button...

However, any query (data the you want to access and modify in your app) should be in the `viewDidLoad` (or a similar method) so that the values are there before the button is pressed. These values should be stored in arrays. And when the button *is* pressed, you will already have access to the values and it'll be easier to modify them in the future and in different methods.

This needs to be shortened.

But, assuming you still want to do it this way the button logic needs to be broken down into functions.

Create a function out of that query and then reference it in the button. Too many things are happening + you're calling the button in the wrong place.

This is a very rough example:

Your button should look something *like* this:

```
  @IBAction func favButton(sender: UIButton) {

    buttonPressed = !buttonPressed

    if buttonPressed == true {

        let followedObjectId = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String

        if isFollowing[followedObjectId!] == true {

            //something needs to happen here?

        }

        updateImage()

    } else  {


      followersUpdate()

    }

   }


      //Your functions below the button: 

 func followersUpdate() {

    let followedObjectId = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String

    if isFollowing[followedObjectId!] == false {

    isFollowing[followedObjectId!] = true
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "fave_on@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    print("follow")

    let following = PFObject(className: "Followers")
    following["following"] = userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String
    following["follower"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
    favLabel.text = "Favourite Jammer"

    following.saveInBackground()

    } else {

    }

}

func updateImage() {
        if buttonPressed != true {

            isFollowing[followedObjectId!] = false
            print("notFollow")
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "fave_off@2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            favLabel.text = "Add to favourites?"


            let query = PFQuery(className: "Followers")

            query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
            query.whereKey("following", equalTo: (userToShowDetail?["name"] as? String)!)

            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                if let objects = objects {

                    for object in objects {

                        object.deleteInBackground()

                    }
                }

            })

        }

    }

    //Your viewDidLoad() initial query to parse:  


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let query = PFUser.query()

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let users = objects {

            for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    if user.objectId! != PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {

                        self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                        self.userids.append(user.objectId!)

                        let query = PFQuery(className: "Followers")

                        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId)!)
                        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId!)

                        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                            if let objects = objects {

                                if objects.count > 0 {

                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = true

                                } else {

                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = false

                                }
                            }

                            if self.isFollowing.count == self.usernames.count {

                            }
                        })
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    })
}
```

As I mentioned, this is a rough example to give you an idea of what you should be doing (even though I think the queries and server sending back and forth is 1) superfluous, 2) not needed and 3) will make your app slower.)

If you break it down like this and have less going on in your button, the image should update. You're going to have to play around with this and revise the code/make it much shorter.

Let me know if you have more questions I'll be happy to help.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. Going to have a play around now and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your help I fixed it I was calling the if it was true twice and false once I added my new code in my edited version.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. In the future, try to keep your code as simple as possible.